# How to call PHP-CRUD-API with csfr token for authentication?

Tags: php, api, authentication, cookies, postman

I installed the [web api](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-api-auth) and tried it without the authentication with Postman such as: GET localhost:8080/php_WebAPI/api.php/student.

After that, i installed the authentication file and tried to get the simple authentication csfr token. I got 200 OK and a cookie with:
Name: PHPSESSID
Value: rriacet8a58be5ip3cd5p7ah71

then, i tried to get the same value but with the authentication token that i assumed is the value of the cookie with different forms as documented:

> call API as: api.php?csrf=[csrf token] (session cookie is sent
>   automatically)

some forms i tried

```
GET localhost:8080/php_WebAPI/api.php?csrf=rriacet8a58be5ip3cd5p7ah71/student
GET localhost:8080/php_WebAPI/api.php?csrf=rriacet8a58be5ip3cd5p7ah71&student
GET localhost:8080/php_WebAPI/api.php?PHPSESSID=rriacet8a58be5ip3cd5p7ah71/student
```

I also tired to to add to the authentication and many other methods but all i get is unauthorized.

I read some similar question where answers suggested postman interceptor to get the value of the cookie but i didn't know how to use the plugin.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE1:
I managed to get the token using the following method
[image: getting the authentication token from the x-www-form in the body tab]

the problem is that, i get the same token no mater what i input as a username and password. Also , i get unauthorized when i try to get the data.

Can anyone kindly give me some tips or should i give up on this script?

Comment: I've never used that library before, but from a quick glance it looks like the csrf is supposed to be returned as the body of the response, not as the cookie value.

Comment: I got nothing in the body.

Comment: but when i posted to get the token i got 200 ok and also a cookie

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks to your note, i managed to get the token in the body

Comment: This library is not well maintained. it's just a prove of concept for the creator. If you don't have the knowledge to fix it to your needs , then you will need to use another library. try Slim framework (https://www.slimframework.com/) which has a very friendly support community. or check other frameworks:
https://medium.com/tech-journal/best-5-lightweight-php-frameworks-for-rest-apis-development-55d252706ac7

Comment: @T.Teser Thank you so much for recommending this awesome framework for me. It helped me a lot in creating Rest Web APIs easily